# How to cite only quoted page number to put after a quotion using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style, quoting, csquotes

According to  APA-style rules, [a quoting page number should always appear after the quote itself](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/how-to-cite-direct-quotations.html).

using in text citations, this would look like:

> Palladino and Wade’s (2010) results indicate that “a flexible mind is a healthy mind” (p. 147).

Im having trouble to reproduce this using `biblatex` and `\textcite`. Using `\autocite` still gives me the year and page, not only the page.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\textcite[11]{key} mentioned this as "\textelp{} foo bar.".\\
\textcite{key} mentioned this as "\textelp{} foo bar."\autocite*[11]{key}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pnotecite` should help you here. Like `\notecite` it only prints the optional pre- and postnote arguments and no real citation. But as the name suggests, it also adds parentheses around the output.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[11]{sigfridsson} mentioned this as \enquote{\textelp{} foo bar}.

\textcite{sigfridsson} mentioned this as \enquote{\textelp{} foo bar} \pnotecite[11]{sigfridsson}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If you want full APA style, you may want to consider using `biblatex-apa`'s `style=apa` instead of `style=authoryear-comp`.